# Java get selected folder path

Tags: java, swing

In this application I'm asking the user to choose a folder, however using code below I'm unable to use this input as variable path

```
public class csvtoxls {

    public static void main() throws IOException {

        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
        jfc.setDialogTitle("Wybierz folder do konwersji: ");
        jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        jfc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        int returnValue = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            if (jfc.getSelectedFile().isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("You selected the directory: " + jfc.getSelectedFile());
```

So in order to achieve this I used function:

```
public class getpath {

      public static String pickPath(JFileChooser fileChooser)
      {
        String path = null;
        
        /* create a JFrame to be the parent of the file 
         * chooser open dialog if you don't do this then 
         * you may not see the dialog.
         */
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        
        // get the return value from choosing a file
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        
        // if the return value says the user picked a file 
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
          path = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        return path;
        
      }
}
```

Variable:

```
Path workDir = Paths.get(getpath.pickPath(jfc));
```

The problem with this solution is that user have to choose folder twice which can easily lead to mistake. Is there way to get this path easier?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: What doesn't work about the first approach? Both are a JFileChooser... so they both expose getSelectedFile() to return the string value of the path. Just put it in a variable someplace and use it.

Comment: imo its problem with eclipse wich display compilation error

Comment: I FIXED IT POSTING SOLUTION: Path workDir = jfc.getSelectedFile().toPath();